# How do I move a WooCommerce website from Google Cloud to a production server?

Tags: woocommerce, google-cloud-platform, production-environment

I created a Woocommerce website on Google Cloud for staging and sharing with the owner. But now I need to buy server space and move it to prod. I'm never done this before, a step by step guidance will help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you already have a Woocommerce website on Google Cloud, so, I think you are using your free trial account that includes $300 US dollars.
Precisely, these kind of accounts are designed to get a better picture on how much does GCP would cost for you and experiment with solutions that GCP offers, you can create Virtual Machines with your website and make stress tests to check what machine type works for you.  Also you can increase or decrease your resources according to your needs.

You can find a table that summarizes your hosting options on Google Cloud in the following [link](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/web-serving-overview#choosing_an_option)

You can consult the following [link](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/web-hosting) to have a better idea on what solution could be useful to you.

To check the cost of the GCP products you can access the following link where you will find the [lists of all pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/all-pricing) for Compute Engine.

Once you know what type of machine could work four you you can use the [GCP Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) to make an estimate.

Also, you can use Google Cloud Deployment Manager to create a set of Google Cloud resources and manage them as a deployment.
You can make the configuration file part of your team's code repository, and then you can create the same environment with consistent results to create your production server.

I found a [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/quickstart) for Google Cloud Deployment Manager to create a virtual machine (VM) instance where you can define the VM in a basic configuration file, and use that configuration file to create a deployment.

On the other hand, I recommend you to review the following guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to provide a better context on what you are doing and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into all these links.